# Grid hooks to change dynamically change table headers on the fly

Tags: grid

I am looking for a hook where I can dynamically change the table headers of a displayed Grid field in the frontend on the fly.

There are hooks for grid, grid_query and grid_save. So far in the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/grid/index.html), I don't see anything where I can change the table headers output text.

Am I just missing something in these hooks or is there no way to change the table headers output other than editing the core files?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the Grid-related hooks won't help you here. You probably want to look at either the [channel_entries_row](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel/index.html#channel-entries-row) hook (for access to the raw data after it's been queried), or the [template-post-parse](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/template/index.html#template-post-parse)  hook (for access to the complete template after it's been parsed).

Comment: Nice. I will look into this and see if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.